# Get NaN in Math.pow operation with second parameter as a decimal value

Tags: javascript

I have a equation with a square with root=5:

[image]
<sub>(source: [xpg.com.br](http://www.jonataspiazzi.xpg.com.br/eq.png))</sub>

I need to write this equation in javascript so:

```
var y = Math.pow(-x, 1 / 5); // or Math.pow(-x, 0.2);
```

So far, so good.
But when i try the value `x = 400`.

```
var y = Math.pow(-400, 0.2);
```

I'm aways get `NaN`, but this equation returns a Real value.
If I use my calc or google or any other calc I get something like:

`(-400) ^ 0.2 = -3.31445401734`

And this is correct. But the javascript is screwing up with me.

Any one can tell me why and/or how to fix it?

Comment: In Python, `pow(-400, 0.2)` also returns a complex. Weird.

Comment: `-1 ^ 0.2 === -1`, so do `-Math.pow(400, 0.2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is according to the ECMAScript Specification section [**15.8.2.13**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.13):

> `pow (x, y)`
>
> - If `x < 0` and `x` is finite and `y` is finite and `y` is not an integer, the
>     result is `NaN`.

In our case `x` is finite and is less than `0`, while `y` is a finite float number.

**REF:** http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.13

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact

```
y = (-x) ^ (1/5)
  = (-1) ^ (1/5) * x ^ (1/5)
  = -1 * x ^ (1/5)
```

To simplify your problem to

```
-Math.pow(400, 0.2);
```

Which won't cause errors